# What was Randyll Tarly's stand after Renly's death?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* during the **War of the Five Kings**, Randyll Tarly was originally standing with Renly Baratheon's claim for the throne, but what about after Renly's death?

Is it ever mentioned what side he picked after that? Is it ever addressed in the books?

I know his stand in season 7 but I am concerned about his stand in the War of the Five Kings immediately after Renly's death.

Comment: For the show specifically, the fact that he's been absent, and how he is portrayed in the family dinner with Sam and Gilly, it stands to reason that Randyll has been absent from the game  for a while. His only claim to loyalty used to be to the Tyrells, and when Randyll talked about that loyalty, it sounded like it hadn't been actively called upon. So It's likely that he has simply not been part of the game in any pronounced way until he reappeared this season.

Comment: Tarly joined Renly because his liege Lord Mace Tyrell did with a marital pact. When Renly died, he joined his Lord in new pact with Joffrey Baratheon and Tommen Baratheon. It is address in the books in great detail. If you would like an answer from books, feel free to ask this on SF&F.

Comment: @Aegon I have never read books and majorly concerned about show only but answer with the support from book are fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Season 7, Episode 2, when Jaime tries to convert Tarly to the Lannister cause, Tarly responds something like this:

> I swore an oath to House Tyrell. I’ve known Olenna since
>   I was a child.

It's not far-fetched to derive from this that up until then he simply always followed whatever allegiance house Tyrell had. So even your premise for the war of the five kings is a bit misguided. He did not declare directly for Renly, rather he was as always a loyal bannerman of house Tyrell, which supported Renly. So it makes sense that after the war, up until the explosion of the great sept of Baelor he supported Tommen Baratheon and thus indirectly the Lannisters because they were in allegiance with the Tyrells. In the aftermath of that explosions he likely still supports the Tyrells but before any real action happens Jaime persuades him to change sides.

Comment: It could be included as further evidence that Randyll Tarly also supported the Tyrells in declaring for King Aerys during Robert's Rebellion, even going so far as to defeat Robert in battle.